# Accessing VMware Virtual Machine through SSH

Tags: networking, ssh, vmware-workstation, kali-linux

I want to connect to my VMware Kali Linux VM through SSH. Open-SSH server and client is already installed and here are my current VM settings:

[image]

I am running VMware Workstation. Here is what is showing up on my router settings:

[image]

However, when I tried to SSH into this Kali machine, I am getting timed out. I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how to fix this. I would also like to port forward it, so that I can access it anytime I want, without actually bringing my computer.

Comment: Where are you connecting from?  Your VMware host?  Another physical computer on your local network?  Somewhere outside your local network (i.e., on the other side of the router)?  Do you have network connectivity?  E.g., can you ping?

Comment: I am connecting from my physical computer. However, I want to connect it from outside my LAN network. Yes, I have network connectivity